# MatBottomSheet closeOnNavigation only works for back/forward on browser but not on routing itself

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

i'm facing an issue currently in my app, I'm having multiple web components loaded in a dashboard, when accessing a specific app, I have a button displaying a bottom sheet as a post-it

```
this.bottomSheet.open(PostItComponent, {
          data: {
            'postIt': this.postIt,
            'isNewPostIt': isNewPostIt
          },
          hasBackdrop: false,
          closeOnNavigation: true,
});
```

My problem is: when the user clicks to access another page, the bottom sheet stays but I expected it to be gone with the closeOnNavigation to true, did anyone faced the issue before and has an idea on how to close it automatically ?

I tried using ngOnDestroy but the component itself is not destroyed as it just loads another web component.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.bottomSheetRef.dismiss();
}
```

Thanks for the hints and advices you will provide

Comment: The angular router has a [`NavigationStart` event](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular#router) that you could set up to dismiss your sheet component before navigation occurs. Maybe that's a better place than `ngOnDestroy()`?

Comment: Does the URL change? What is your app's LocationStrategy? How are you injecting MatBottomSheet? Sheet closure on navigation changes happen because MatBottomSheetRef subscribes to changes on a Location object. MatBottomSheetRef gets the Location from MatBottomSheet which declares it in its constructor. So if the Location doesn't exist where MatBottomSheet is injected, a subscription doesn't get created and nothing happens on navigation. And if the URL change is not the same type as your app's LocationStrategy, a change event won't be triggered.